# How can I verify in groovy assert either value is a string or null

Tags: groovy

I have one response object of a REST call which is having JSON data.
I am using groovy to verify one key value either it should be a string or null

For example

```
assert response.data.item.key
```

So key can be a string or a null. How can I put assertion on this key value?

Answer (score 1):

Assert could look like:

```
def key = response.data.item.key
assert null == key || String == key.getClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want only a String?

If you use a groovy string or some other char sequence checking its class equals String will fail

```
def key = response.data.item.key
assert key == null || key instanceof CharSequence
```

May be better...